# one combine example of spring + hibernate + maven in java

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven

I want one combine example of spring + hibernate + maven in Java. So please help me and give me one example of this.

I want this example for the creating the Java-based application.

Comment: Browse in Internet. why u r post the Question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some very good examples on Github for Spring + Hibernate + Maven by John Thompson:

https://github.com/springframeworkguru

Comment: This site is useful for me and I have learne lots of concepts.